# TFS Build Controller service HTTP code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException

Tags: tfs

I have configured the TFS 2013 build service but the build controller fails after  5 seconds with error

Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
  HTTP code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException

I tried modifying the web.config Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Message Queue but no luck

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a48e3951-d984-4648-ad24-a18ed09de97b/tfs-2012-builds-stuck-at-just-started?forum=tfsbuild

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at Task Manager on the machine where your TFS Repository lives.  We have this problem whenever its memory utilization is greater than 95%.

Comment: Just had the same issue and that was the cause. Getting the memory usage under 95% manage to get build service up again... that's a weird bug actually...

Comment: Had the same problem after upgrading from Team Foundation Build 2010 to Team Foundation Build 2013.  It did NOT happen until I did the upgrade.  When I see this kind of memory utilization it is almost always on the single server configuration of Team Foundation Server (Application Tier and Data Tier on the same machine) where the SQL Server Max Memory has not been set.  SQL Server will continue to consume as much physical memory as it can.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and in our case it was resolved after lowering the memory usage of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I set the build service property to set the domain user and and also Changed the tfs site in IIS to connect as same user.Not sure if this was the issue.

Then i just restarted the TFS server machine and build server .Build service did not show this error.
No modification was made to the webconfig files